# How to add image to ExpantionTile in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

I've been working on an app in which **I want to add an image in the `ExpansionTile` function** but the catch is that flutter don't allow us to add image in that.

For the reference, **this is what I'm trying to implement**, this exact same UI has also been implemented on Myntra app.

> Check out Myntra UI here: https://vimeo.com/707250315

[image]

I've tried searching for some alternatives for this and I found [expandable package](https://pub.dev/packages/expandable) which does the same thing but is not exactly what I want to achieve. **I managed to implement this for now**:

[image]

If anyone of you have implemented this UI before, I would love to see how it's implemented.

Comment: You can try conditional if to show the widget or `Visibility` widget

Comment: Is it possible for you to add a short video of both behaviors so that the end goal can be clearly seen?

Comment: Hey @O'neya, I've attached a link to demonstrate the UI which is to be implemented

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

In my research for a solution to this, I concluded AnimatedContainer() would be the best suited for the primary tile. This first snippet is the general widget. At the very end, I have modeled a List of Map<String, dynamic> that represents a possible JSON response

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import '/widgets/category_item.dart';

class CategoriesPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const CategoriesPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<CategoriesPage> createState() => _CategoriesPageState();
}

class _CategoriesPageState extends State<CategoriesPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: _products.length,
        itemBuilder: (ctx, index) => CategoryItem(product: _products[index]),
      ),
    );
  }
}

List<Map<String, dynamic>> _products = [
  {
    'categoryTitle': 'Summer Shop',
    'categoryDescription': 'Turn up the heat in style',
    'categoryImage':
        'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1600566752355-35792bedcfea?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8Nnx8YmF0aHJvb218ZW58MHx8MHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60',
    'subCategory': [
      {'categ': 'Top Brands'},
      {'categ': 'Men'},
      {'categ': 'Women'},
      {'categ': 'Kids'},
      {'categ': 'Footware'},
      {'categ': 'Accessories'},
      {'categ': 'Jewellery'},
      {'categ': 'Beauty'},
    ],
  },
  {
    'categoryTitle': 'Men',
    'categoryDescription': 'T-shorts, Shirts,Jeans,Accessories',
    'categoryImage':
        'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1603825491103-bd638b1873b0?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8OXx8YmF0aHJvb218ZW58MHx8MHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60',
    'subCategory': [
      {'categ': 'Top Brands'},
      {'categ': 'Men'},
      {'categ': 'Women'},
      {'categ': 'Kids'},
      {'categ': 'Footware'},
      {'categ': 'Accessories'},
      {'categ': 'Jewellery'},
      {'categ': 'Beauty'},
    ],
  },
  {
    'categoryTitle': 'Women',
    'categoryDescription': 'T-shorts, Shirts,Jeans,Accessories',
    'categoryImage':
        'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1603825491103-bd638b1873b0?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8OXx8YmF0aHJvb218ZW58MHx8MHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60',
    'subCategory': [
      {'categ': 'Top Brands'},
      {'categ': 'Men'},
      {'categ': 'Women'},
      {'categ': 'Kids'},
      {'categ': 'Footware'},
      {'categ': 'Accessories'},
      {'categ': 'Jewellery'},
      {'categ': 'Beauty'},
    ],
  },
  {
    'categoryTitle': 'Kids',
    'categoryDescription': 'T-shorts, Shirts,Jeans,Accessories',
    'categoryImage':
        'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1603825491103-bd638b1873b0?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8OXx8YmF0aHJvb218ZW58MHx8MHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60',
    'subCategory': [
      {'categ': 'Top Brands'},
      {'categ': 'Men'},
      {'categ': 'Women'},
      {'categ': 'Kids'},
      {'categ': 'Footware'},
      {'categ': 'Accessories'},
      {'categ': 'Jewellery'},
      {'categ': 'Beauty'},
    ],
  },
];
```

This is the builder part. Update with Expandable packge

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:expandable/expandable.dart';

class CategoryItem extends StatefulWidget {
  final Map<String, dynamic> product;
  const CategoryItem({required this.product, Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<CategoryItem> createState() => _CategoryItemState();
}

class _CategoryItemState extends State<CategoryItem> {
  final _controller = ExpandableController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final deviceSize = MediaQuery.of(context).size;

    return ExpandablePanel(
      controller: _controller,
      theme: const ExpandableThemeData(hasIcon: false),
      header: Container(
        height: deviceSize.height * .13,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          image: DecorationImage(
            fit: BoxFit.cover,
            image: NetworkImage(widget.product['categoryImage']),
          ),
        ),
      ),
      collapsed: const SizedBox(height: 0),
      expanded: ListView.builder(
        shrinkWrap: true,
        physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(),
        itemCount: widget.product['subCategory'].length,
        itemBuilder: (ctx, index) => ExpansionTile(
          childrenPadding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 5),
          title: Text(widget.product['subCategory'][index]['categ']),
          children: List<Widget>.generate(
            widget.product['subCategory'].length,
            (index) => Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                Text(widget.product['subCategory'][index]['categ']),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: That's a very nice approach but the main purpose of this UI is to eliminate the text from the banner

Comment: @littleironical I have updated the code to have the entire banner as an image. Copy entire sections again and it should work as described